# How to enable google maps android api for smooth two finger zoom?

Tags: android, google-maps

On the original google maps if I use two fingers to zoom in or out the zoom animation does not stop immediately after releasing the screen. It continues to zoom in or out respectively slowly a little more. This is nice, but on my google maps api when I zoom in or out with 2 fingers the zoom animation stops as soon as I release my fingers from the screen. Is there any way to enable this feature? Probably there is.. I just don't know the name of this effect... maybe zoom echo? :)

Comment: I don't understand why people down voted this question. That's a good question. Zoom in transitions in Google Maps application is smoother. I checked other popular apps such as Uber, Lyft, Expedia and they all have this problem on their Map Activity.

Comment: I never got a solution to this... but introduction of new methods and deprecating of methods is so fast in these classes that by the time you would finish an app... half the methods would be outdated by then... so given up on these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html

Comment: Well, I've seen that link before and has not solved the problem... these two command can disable/enable zoom control buttons (+,-) and zoom gestures. Please check your latest Google Maps APP (original) on your device and you will see when zoom in or out using your fingers and release during that then zoom effect will continue for a little more and DOES NOT stop immediately. This is the effect (feature) I am looking for to enable in the Google Maps API. Thanks anyway, and my deepest disrespect for those who skim read and voted my question down...

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code :

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                int zoomLevel = (int) mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
                if(previousZoomLevel != (int) mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                {
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabledDuringRotateOrZoom(false);
                    Log.e("setOnCameraMoveStartedListener",zoomLevel+"");
                }
                previousZoomLevel = (int) mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
            }
        });

   

     mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraIdle() {
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabledDuringRotateOrZoom(true);
        }    
     });
```